# Microsoft Office Interop Excel - Specify name of Excel file

Tags: c#, excel, interop, ms-office

I use Microsoft Office Interop Excel for create excel file.  My problem is that I dont know how specify name of excel file.

**Variables:**

```
// Excel object references.
private Application _excelApp;
private Workbooks _books;
private _Workbook _book;
private Sheets _sheets;
private _Worksheet _sheet;
```

**Create excel file:**

```
_excelApp = new Application();
_books = _excelApp.Workbooks;

_book = _books.Add(_optionalValue);

_sheets = _book.Worksheets;
_sheet = (_Worksheet)(_sheets.Item[1]);
_sheet.Name = sheetName;
```

How can I specify name of excel file during creating excel file? Sorry for my english.

EDIT:

I know that I can use

```
_book.SaveAs(fileName)
```

Comment: I answered before you included your edit.  If you know about SaveAs, then what additional functionality do you mean?  What are you hoping to achieve that SaveAs does not fulfil your requirements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you have created the Excel workbook and copies the data you want, you can simply save it as such

```
_book.SaveAs(outputPath, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, 
                            Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
```

The Type.Missing parameters were appropriate to my code that I took this snippet from, but you may have need for inclusion.

Answer (score 0):

i think you should [check this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/asmxandxml/thread/a316f8ac-6423-4716-b7a7-b8bbf8dbea72). From the linked page:

```
public virtual void SaveAs (
    [OptionalAttribute] Object Filename,
    [OptionalAttribute] Object FileFormat,
    [OptionalAttribute] Object Password,
    [OptionalAttribute] Object WriteResPassword,
    [OptionalAttribute] Object ReadOnlyRecommended,
    [OptionalAttribute] Object CreateBackup,
    [OptionalAttribute] XlSaveAsAccessMode AccessMode,
    [OptionalAttribute] Object ConflictResolution,
    [OptionalAttribute] Object AddToMru,
    [OptionalAttribute] Object TextCodepage,
    [OptionalAttribute] Object TextVisualLayout,
    [OptionalAttribute] Object Local
)
```